# Is it recommended to use old Macbook charger with M1?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon, charger

I got a 16" 2019 MBP and 16" 2021 M1.

- MBP came with 96W charger with usb-c=>usb-c
- M1 came with 140W charger with usb-c=>magsafe

1. Is it safe and recommended to charge my M1 with the 96W charger?
2. Is it safe and recommended to charge my M1 with usb-c charger?

I'm mostly thinking of the battery and computer health when asking about safety and recommendation.

Comment: The recommended charger is the one that originally came with the machine.

Comment: You can look up how much power each mac can pull. If the wattage of the charger is below that, it will charge slower - if equal or above, it will charge at max speed. Apple chargers are able to detect and supply appropriate charge automatically, no need to be concerned about damage. I think the “yellow” charger question is a separate issue (1 question at a time). https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700

Comment: 1 and 2 are basically the same question. 3 should be a separate question, with a picture.

Comment: I fried a **MagSafe 2** AC adapter that was rated for 60 W, less than the MacBook Pro's 85 W.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by fried? In how long usage?

Comment: @JBallin https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437293/is-it-recommended-to-use-a-macbook-charger-with-yellow-stains moved the 3rd question here

Comment: @SolomonUcko: was that a genuine adapter? For years my MBP was running on a 45W charger.

Answer (score 6):

It is **safe** to charge any Mac (including those with Apple Silicon) with the 96W (or lower/higher) USB-C charger.

Downsides:

- Slower overall charging
- No “fast” charging.

---

[Apple: About Mac power adapters](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700):

> If your Mac uses USB-C to charge, you can charge your Mac notebook
> with any USB-C power adapter or display. For the best charging
> experience, you should use a power adapter or display that provides at
> least the minimum wattage of the power adapter included with your
> MacBook Air, MacBook Pro, or MacBook.

[Apple: Fast charge your 14-inch or 16-inch MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212755):

> The MacBook Air (M2, 2022), MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021), and MacBook
> Pro (16-inch, 2021) support fast charge. When you connect the
> appropriate power source and cable, you can quickly charge your
> battery up to 50 percent in 30 minutes.