# Is it recommended to use a Macbook charger with yellow stains?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charger

Is it safe and recommended to charge my Macbookpro with a usb-c charger that is 2 years old and has yellow stains at the tip?

[image]

Comment: Is this from Apple? If so, run Apple Diagnostics with the charger plugged-in and see if it reports anything. If it doesn't, than this is probably safe to use.

Comment: Yes from Apple, will do

Answer (score 2):

**Is it recommended?** No. It's always recommended to use a cable in good visual and functional condition to charge your likely expensive equipment.

**Is it safe?** It depends. The age doesn't really matter. It appears that the issue is just surface discoloration to the sheathing of the cable, rather than penetrating to the wiring and components inside, but it could also be caused by overheating or stressing the cable. If you want to test it without risking damaging your Macbook, you could try it with an old discarded phone (with an adapter, perhaps) or some other device you no longer care about.

Regardless, the longevity of the cable is likely diminished. If the discoloration is caused by chemical agents, it's more likely to crack or start fraying at the location of the stain in the future, reducing the useful life of the cable.