# Can I use an old power adapter extension cable with new M1?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon, charger

I have 2 Power Adapter Extension Cable's.

16" 2019 MBP: 125V~ 2.5A
16" 2021 M1: 125V~ 7A

Can I use the 2.5A one, on my M1?
Would using the 2019 one with 2.5A be a slower battery charging experience than 7A one?

Comment: Probable duplicate of this question by the OP https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437271/is-it-recommended-to-use-old-macbook-charger-with-m1

Comment: Why would I write a duplicate question? lol

Comment: I suggest you either merge this question into the original one or explain why they are different.

Comment: From numbers, and the units we're talking about something completely different. While the previous answer might cover this, it also might not. There is a 4.5A difference and I want to learn what are the effects of this difference. Previous is a more generic question, this is very specific.

Comment: You should look at the output specs, not the input.

Comment: @SolarMike why? is the cable not harmed if input/output doesn't match?

Comment: This is not duplicate. The other question is about the power adapter. This question is about the extension cable.